# Validating objects with class validator

Tags: node.js, validation, nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I am trying to validate if an object passed is of a certain type.

Country object

```
class Country {
 code : string;
 name: string;
}
```

Validation code

```
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsNotEmptyObject()
  @IsObject()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => Country)
  country: Country;
```

*@Type is imported from class-transformer*

This is the answer which is found in many of the questions on stack overflow.
eg : [Class-validator - validate array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58343262/class-validator-validate-array-of-objects) . It does not work for me. This is for a single object and not an array of objects.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Add the following to your **controller**: Ensure to have `whitelist: true` set to true. (This will strip down everything which is not in Country Schema definition)

```js
@Post()
createExample(@Body(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true })) body: ExampleDto) {
   ...
}
```

Add **your DTO** like this:

```js
class Country {
   @IsString()
   code : string;

   @IsString() // To make a field optional you can add @IsOptional
   name: string;
}

export class ExampleDto {

   // You do not require IsNotEmpty or because with IsString in Country you force it to be required.
   @ValidateNested()
   @Type(() => Country)
   country: Country;
}
```

Comment: @Muljayan Does this answer your question?