# NestJs - Validate an array of objects

Tags: arrays, typescript, validation, nestjs, class-validator

I'm trying to validate an array of objects. I tried the method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58366367) and that works fine for most cases. But the issue I'm facing is that when the array contains another array, the validation does not throw an error. While sending an array with a string the error displayed is `must be either object or array`. So I suppose it accepts an array. How do I stop it from letting through an array of arrays? I need it to only accept objects.

valid

```
{
    "user" : [{ "name" : "kate"}, {"name":"mike"}]
}
```

should be invalid

```
{
    "user" : [[]]
}
```

My validation code

```
export class UserInfo {
  @ApiProperty({ required: true })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  name: string;
}

export class User {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsArray()
  @ArrayMinSize(1)
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => UserInfo)
  user: UserInfo;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is outdated but on GitHub they say "Currently we do not have support for multidimensional arrays."

https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/432#issuecomment-542119540

Comment: Hmm I don't think I'm looking for multidimensional array validation.

Comment: Ahhh I see... Can you share your validation code?

Comment: @LarsFlieger I've added the validation code to the OP.

Comment: Thank you! I tried a few things and it's behaves the same like you say... This is a good question / issue

Comment: So no inbuilt solution for now... guess I'll have to add a custom validation to this.

Comment: Yes, however I think it's worth creating an issue in class-validator... I think this behaviour is not what you expect from it..

Comment: @LarsFlieger it looks like this was already logged there - https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/1597

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why they're not fixing it, spent a few hours to find the "right way" to do it, without success

but this is what's my solution for the same problem but in my context

```
import { IsEnum, IsString, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';
import { Transform, Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { POSTGRESQL_DATA_TYPES_ENUM } from 'src/table/constants';

const isArrayWithNoNestedArrays = (fields) => {
  // early return if fields is not an array
  if (!Array.isArray(fields.value)) return null;

  return fields.value.map((field) => {
    // replace array with not valid value
    // in my case it's null here
    if (Array.isArray(field)) return null;
    return field;
  });
};

class Field {
  @IsString()
  name: string;
  @IsEnum(POSTGRESQL_DATA_TYPES_ENUM)
  type: POSTGRESQL_DATA_TYPES_ENUM;
}

export class CreateTableDto {
  @IsString()
  name: string;
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => Field)
  @Transform(isArrayWithNoNestedArrays)
  fields: Field[];
}
```