# class-validator doesn't validate arrays

Tags: arrays, validation, nestjs, class-validator

I can't get the class-validator to work. It seems like I am not using it: everything works as if I didn't use class-validator. When sending a request with an incorrectly formatted body, I don't have any validation error, although I should.

My DTO:

```ts
import { IsInt, Min, Max } from 'class-validator';

export class PatchForecastDTO {
  @IsInt()
  @Min(0)
  @Max(9)
  score1: number;

  @IsInt()
  @Min(0)
  @Max(9)
  score2: number;
  gameId: string;
}
```

My controller:

```ts
@Patch('/:encid/forecasts/updateAll')
async updateForecast(
    @Body() patchForecastDTO: PatchForecastDTO[],
    @Param('encid') encid: string,
    @Query('userId') userId: string
): Promise<ForecastDTO[]> {
  return await this.instanceService.updateForecasts(userId, encid, patchForecastDTO);
}
```

My bootstrap:

```ts
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  await app.listen(PORT);
  Logger.log(`Application is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`, 'Bootstrap');
}
bootstrap();
```

I can't find what's wrong. What did I miss?

Comment: You need to be much more specific about what is going wrong! Error Messages, behavior etc.

Comment: @FuzzyTemper done

Comment: This was helpful for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58343262/class-validator-validate-array-of-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NestJS actually [does not support array validation out of the box](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/335). In order to validate an array, it must be wrapped in an object.

This way, I would not use a DTO corresponding to a list of items, but a DTO corresponding to *an object* that contains a list of items:

```
import { PatchForecastDTO } from './patch.forecast.dto';
import { IsArray, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';

export class PatchForecastsDTO {
    @IsArray()
    @ValidateNested() // perform validation on children too
    @Type(() => PatchForecastDTO) // cast the payload to the correct DTO type
    forecasts: PatchForecastDTO[];
}
```

And I would use that DTO in my controller:

```
@Patch('/:encid/forecasts/updateAll')
async updateForecast(
    @Body() patchForecastsDTO: PatchForecastsDTO,
    @Param('encid') encid: string,
    @Query('userId') userId: string
): Promise<ForecastDTO[]> {
  return await this.instanceService.updateForecasts(userId, encid, patchForecastsDTO);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In the current version of NestJS (7.6.14), validating a request body that is a JSON array is supported using the built in `ParseArrayPipe`.

```js
@Post()
createBulk(
  @Body(new ParseArrayPipe({ items: CreateUserDto }))
  createUserDtos: CreateUserDto[],
) {
  return 'This action adds new users';
}
```

See the [official docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#parsing-and-validating-arrays) or the [source code](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/pipes/parse-array.pipe.ts) for more info.